# Cannot chown or chmod using sudo anymore

Tags: 12.04, command-line, sudo, root, chmod

I was trying to make an adjustment to the /etc/sudoers file, and I accidentally corrupted it.
I restored it via the grub and using the Ubuntu 14.04 default.

But now it seems I can change ownership or permissions when trying to run sudo chown and sudo chmod. I cant even sudo sh.

I just get the following error:

> sudo: chown: command not found

Is there anything that I might have lost in the sudoers file that was allowing me to run these commands?

This is my output of $PATH

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

This is the output from: whereis sudo chown

> sudo: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib/sudo /usr/bin/X11/sudo /usr/share/man/man8/sudo.8.gz
>   chown: /bin/chown /usr/share/man/man2/chown.2.gz /usr/share/man/man1/chown.1.gz

Also.. This is where I got the Generic Ubuntu 14.04 sudoers file from.
http://heggel4.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/repair-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Please help. I'm in over my head :/
Thanks all :)

Comment: Post output of `echo "$PATH"`

Comment: @user68186 I already saw this other thread and was able to use it to fix my sudoers file, but I still cannot run any of the following commands: chown, chmod, sh. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @ElefantPhace I added the output of the $PATH not really sure what to do with it?

Comment: Hmm... Post output of `whereis sudo chown`

Comment: @ElefantPhace I added that output as well. I hope it helps.. I'm really quite stuck here :(

Comment: Can you use `chown` without using `sudo`? Test on a file you own or just type `chown`

Comment: @ElefantPhace Ahh I didnt think about that ... looks like I can't do it... comes with the error: chown: missing operand ... Did I uninstall it somehow ??

Comment: No that means that it can find it. Something is still wrong with `sudo` though

Comment: @ElefantPhace Ah yea... just tried it with a file and it worked.. I'm lost, any ideas?

Comment: Make sure your `secure_path` in sudoers matches what is on the page you linked to.

Comment: @ElefantPhace Yup its an exact match. I copy pasted it.
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: Just noticed that I can't even run sudo ls which means sudo is stuffed. Does this have something to do with permissions of root maybe? groups?

Comment: Ah I'm thinking this may have something to do with ZSH.. damn that stupid sudoers file :D Wish I had a photographic memory!

Comment: The error you got means that chown is not found, if sudoers file is exaclty as link you post, it's really strange tha it doesn't work. Did you edit sudoers file from Windows?